# LM741 OP amp noob question

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, function-generator

[image: Capture.png]

I have copied a schematic from my school project, and the task is to simulate it in pspice then do it in real life using a oscilloscope and function generator. I can't even do the first step which is to simulate it. I don't know what to put in AF in and AF out and where to put the sinus power source. Also I don't know if the Vdc represents V+ like it does in my schematic :S

Can you guys please help me...

Comment: It doesn't use a sinus power supply - it's got a 12V supply as shown in your diagram.

Comment: The schematic says V+ i thought it was a regular dc power supply, but idk.. The thing is i want to simulate it so i get a sinuswave then do it in real life and compare results

Comment: That green circle in PSPICE/Orcad means you have an open circuit.

Comment: It was a error i fixed, unconnected wires

Comment: 741? Really? When will this Thing die already?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, and they said we'd never make an electronic cockroach.

Comment: Is the circuit negative feedback dominant or positive feedback dominant ?

Comment: The plus and minus inputs of the opamp are inverted in your schematic.

Comment: @PlasmaHH  count(is:question 741) = 101 as of now.  It lives!

Comment: They're teaching 741s in school? In 2017? It makes you weep.

Answer (score 1):

Connect V2 two AFin and ground.  Spice is not going to like C3 hanging out there with no path to ground. Add a 1Meg resistor between AFout and ground.  The amplifier will have a gain of about 100.  Set the VAMPL=0.01 for starters.  This will get you about 1V out a low frequencies.  Try setting Frequency to 1kHz to start.  Run a transient simulation for about 5ms to see about 5 cycles of AC.   The AC input is not used for transient analysis so you can leave it empty.  The OFFSET doesn't matter since C2 will block any DC at the input.

Comment: Perhaps the OP circuit was *intended* as an amplifier, but as shown, it is a hysteresis switch, not an amplifier. Your suggestions for connection of V2, C3 make sense in any case.

Comment: You are correct glen_geek.  This is not set up as an amplifier.  My mistake for not noticing the feedback was to the non inverting input.